# Reformulation of optimization problem

Tags: quadratic-programming

I am looking for some helps concerning an optimization problem.
I have an optimization problem defined on two sets  $\mathcal{X}=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n $ and $\mathcal{Y}=\{y_j\}_{j=1}^m $ and described as follows 
$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 & \underset{\alpha, \beta}{\text{max}}
 & & \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^T x_i-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^Tx_j \alpha_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i}+\sum_{k=1}^m \beta_k y_k^T y_k-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^m \beta_k y_k^Ty_l \beta_l}{\sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j }\\
 & \text{subject to} 
 & & 0 \leq \alpha \leq C1 \\
 & 
 & &   0 \leq \beta \leq C2 \\
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
where $C1$ and $C2$ are two given parameters. I'm asking if the above problem can be rewritten in the follwing form
$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 & \underset{X}{\text{max}}
 & &  \frac{ X^T H X}{X}+A^TX\\ %\mathbf {1}_N
 & \text{subject to} 
 & & 0 \leq X \leq C \\
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
If yes what would be the value of $H$,$A$ and $X$ and if not how can I optimize the first formulation by matlab knowing that the second formulation can be optimized in matlab by CVX package for convex optimization using its "quad_over_lin" function.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.Exchange. Is the $X$ a vector? If it is, how can you divide by a vector in your reformulation?

Comment: Presumably the denominator should be $B^{T}X$ where $B$ is a constant vector (in this case it would be the vector of all ones.)

Comment: Yes, as noted by Mr. Brian Borchers, the denominator take the form of $ B^T X$ where $B $is a vector of ones and $X$ depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question sounds a lot like a homework exercise, so I'll simply give a couple of hints.

1. Break your objective into the sum of two of two terms, and then use the "epigraph trick" on each separately.  So, you'd have

$\max s + t$

subject to

$s \leq -\mbox{quad_over_lin(...)}$

$t \leq -\mbox{quad_over_lin(...)}$

2. Recognize that the two parts of your objective function are already almost in quad_over_lin form.  How can you write

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} x_{i}^{T}x_{j} \alpha_{j}$

as

$\| X\alpha \|_{2}^{2}$?

Comment: Thanks Mr Brian for your answers. I have used your answer to a problem presented in http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/minimization-of-normalized-constrained-quadratic-function